# How to stop HTML injection and reflected XSS on Swagger-UI ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, openapi

We have implemented the Swagger UI in an ASP.NET Core Web API project and we are getting feedback from my internal security team that this Swagger UI has some HTML injection and reflected XSS on Swagger-UI.

Please let me know, how can I stop this attack?

This is the implemented code:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";

                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/internal/swagger.json", "internal");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/external/swagger.json", "external");
                c.OAuthClientId(azure.ClientId);
                c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
                c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
                { "resource", azure.ClientId  }
                });
});
```

I have tried to update the Swagger libraries to latest version (6.5.0)

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations
```

but I still have the same issue. I need solution for this case.

Thank you

Comment: I'd ask the security team for more specific information about the problem.  It could be a false positive, could be non-exploitable if the source of the data is trusted, could be a non-issue entirely if the Swagger UI isn't enabled in Production (is it?), could be something you can't correct in the 3rd party tool at all and need to re-think your use of the tool, etc.  Currently the only information you have is "some page somewhere might have some problem".